# getting video from canon vc-c50i camera and sensoray framegrabber

Tags: ros, gscam, image-view, camera-drivers, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get the video stream from a canon vc-c50i camera which connects to a sensoray 311 framegrabber on a MobileRobots Guiabot.  Have tried gscam with

GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-rgb ! identity name=ros"

but image is scrambled.  What should the pipeline be for this camera type?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9730/getting-video-from-canon-vc-c50i-camera-and-sensoray-framegrabber/) by [Liz Murphy](https://answers.ros.org/users/425/liz-murphy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2011-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try `video/x-raw-yuv` or put `ffmpegcolorspace` as the last parameter.

---

Originally posted by [Charence](https://answers.ros.org/users/908/charence/) with karma: 137 on 2011-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My problem was fixed by running: v4l2-ctl -s ntsc, the default setup was PAL hence the scrambling.

---

Originally posted by [Liz Murphy](https://answers.ros.org/users/425/liz-murphy/) with karma: 83 on 2011-11-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2